# WP_Ajax Hook doesn't execute this PHP code

Tags: ajax

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updating_heat_value','updating_heat_value');
add_action('wp_ajax_updating_heat_value','updating_heat_value');
add_action('wp_ajax_update_reading_history','update_reading_history');

function update_reading_history() {
global $post;
if(is_normal_post()) {
        $postiddx2 = get_the_ID();
        $thepost = get_post($postiddx2);
        if(!(wp_is_post_revision($thepost)))
        {
        $userid1 = get_current_user_id();
        $loggedreadinghistory = get_user_meta($userid1, 'readinghistory', true);
        if($loggedreadinghistory == '') {
            $readinghistory = $postiddx2;
            update_user_meta($userid1, 'readinghistory', $readinghistory);
        }
        else
        {
            $readinghistory = $loggedreadinghistory;
            $readinghistory = $readinghistory.','.$postiddx2;
            update_user_meta($userid1, 'readinghistory', $readinghistory);
        }
        }
}
exit();
}

function updating_heat_value()
{
global $post;
if(is_single())
{
    $postiddx = get_the_ID();
    $timenow = time();
    $heatvaluedate = get_post_meta($postiddx, 'heatvaluedate');
    if((get_post_meta($postiddx, 'heatvalue') == '') || $heatvaluedate == '')
    {
        update_post_heat_value($postiddx);
    }
    elseif(($timenow - $heatvaluedate) >= 600)
    {
        update_post_heat_value($postiddx);
    }
}
exit();
}
```

I would like to add this PHP code to the wp_ajax hook, but I don't know how these functions don't get executed.
What could be the problem? Is this the optimal way to do something like this?

Comment: Can you post the associated JavaScript that's making the call to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `get_the_ID` inside your callback function, but `get_the_ID` will only work inside the loop.

You should send your post ID to your callback function explicitly instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah, that could be the problem :) BTW: I knew that raccoons have a helping nature :D